# Matlab gives no result when I use the integral function

Tags: matlab, integral

When trying to calculate the Integral of two variables, I got nothing!

Here is the code:

```
syms x;
a=0.4;
theta=(9 - 4*x*(5*x - 141/25))^(1/2)/2 - 3/2;
theta_prime=-(40*x - 564/25)/(4*(9 - 4*x*(5*x - 141/25))^(1/2));
g=(1/theta)*theta_prime
s=(1+a*(theta-1))*(g)^2
sgen = int(s,x,0.1,1) %x=0.1:0.1: 1
```

What was my mistake?
It supposed to be one value, such as '4.86'. 
Please advise.

Comment: What does "I got nothing" mean? Surely `sgen` is a symbolic object?

Answer (score 4):

`sgen` is a symbolic object representing the integral of your function `s`. You can cast it to double to obtain a numerical value for your integral:

```matlab
syms x;
a=0.4;
theta=(9 - 4*x*(5*x - 141/25))^(1/2)/2 - 3/2;
theta_prime=-(40*x - 564/25)/(4*(9 - 4*x*(5*x - 141/25))^(1/2));
g=(1/theta)*theta_prime;
s=(1+a*(theta-1))*(g)^2;
sgen = double(int(s,x,0.1,1)) % returns 4.8694
```

But if you're not interested in the symbolic equation for the integral, there really is no point in using the symbolic toolbox for this. It is much faster to compute the integral numerically. One way to do so is to create a function `s(x)` and then use `integral` to find the numerical integration. Do note that `s(x)` must be vectorized on the `x` variable for this to work (`integral` will call it with a vector of `x` values to save time). For vectorized computation, it is necessary to add dots in front of some of the `*`, `/` and `^` operators. This is the result:

```matlab
a = 0.4;
theta = @(x) (9 - 4*x.*(5*x - 141/25)).^(1/2)/2 - 3/2;
theta_prime = @(x) -(40*x - 564/25)./(4*(9 - 4*x.*(5*x - 141/25)).^(1/2));
g = @(x) (1./theta(x)).*theta_prime(x);
s = @(x) (1+a*(theta(x)-1)).*g(x).^2;
sgen = integral(s,0.1,1.0) % returns 4.8694
```

Comment: Just got same [result with WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28%281%2B0.4*%28%289+-+4*x*%285*x+-+141%2F25%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F2+-+3%2F2-1%29%29*%28%281%2F%28%289+-+4*x*%285*x+-+141%2F25%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F2+-+3%2F2%29%29*-%2840*x+-+564%2F25%29%2F%284*%289+-+4*x*%285*x+-+141%2F25%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%5E2%2Cx%2C0.1%2C1%29)

Comment: @Cris_Luengo I found my error and then saw you comment. Everything matches now. Thanks

Comment: Great. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @user3311415 Accept the answer (and don't vandalize your question) if it helped you.